# Find the closest combination of two related numbers in a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array, nearest-neighbor

I need to search and compare the nearest combination of two numbers in a multidimensional array based on an user input.

At the moment i have something like that to find the nearest matching number for like "one number".

```
var count= [10, 20, 30, 40],

  goal = userinput

  var closest = count.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return (Math.abs(curr - goal) < Math.abs(prev - goal) ? curr : prev);
  });

$('#result').attr('value', closest);
```

What i want to do: When the user enters ***19*** in **userinput1** and ***4*** in **userinput2** it should be searching and comparing for the nearest combination of numbers in the multidimensional array ***counts***.

```
<input id="userinput1 " value="19" type="text">
<input id="userinput2 " value="4" type="text">
```

-

```
var userinput1 = $('#userinput1 ').val();
var userinput2 = $('#userinput2 ').val();

counts = [['10', '5'], ['20', '10']];

goal = [[userinput1, userinput2]];

/* NEEDED SCRIPT */

$('#result1').attr('value', closest1);
$('#result2').attr('value', closest2);
```

In this example it should choose ['20', '10'] and output both numbers in different variables.

The HTML result should be:

```
<input id="result1" value="20" type="text">
<input id="result2" value="10" type="text">
```

Comment: What if `input1` is close to the first number of one element, while `input2` is close to the second number of a different element? How do you determine the closeness of both numbers? If you can come up with a combined formula, you can then just use the same solution as when you were just processing one input.

Comment: Why is the goal a doubly-nested array? `[[userinput1, userinput2]]` instead of `[userinput1, userinput2]`?

Comment: would you like to compare each of the user inputs against the values, or does the order matters and the unser input should be compared to the same index of the inner counts?

Comment: I just achieved to compare the one number to another. There is no specific reason for the doubly-nested array. I just thought it would be necessary.

Comment: @Barmar The two numbers are always belongin to each other. In my user input example of 19,4:

Comment: @Barmar The two numbers are always belongin to each other. In my user input example of 19 and 4 -> 10 is 9 away from 19 and 5 is 1 away from 4 (9 and 1 away). 20 is also 1 away from 19 but 10 is just 6 away from 4 (1 and 6 away). 1 and 6 is less than 9 and 1 so it should choose the combination 20 and 10. Sorry if it's confusing.

Comment: So just add the two differences, and minimize that sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For comparing index wise absolute depats, you could get the delta first and then return the array depending on the sum.

```js
const addAbsDelta = g => (s, v, i) => s + Math.abs(v - g[i]);

var counts = [[10, 5], [20, 10]],
    goal = [19, 4],
    result = counts.reduce((a, b) =>
        a.reduce(addAbsDelta(goal), 0) < b.reduce(addAbsDelta(goal), 0) ? a : b
    );
    
console.log(result);
```

For getting a result where one of the values match, you need to get a product of the absolute deltas and the sum of the absolute delta for an order of the result and take the smallest.

```js
function getApproximation(counts, goal) {
    const
        p = (r, v, i) => r * Math.abs(v - goal[i]),   // moves zeros to top
        s = (r, v, i) => r + Math.abs(v - goal[i]),   // allowes sorting
        score = a => a.reduce(p, 1) + a.reduce(s, 0); // get product and sum

    return counts
        .filter(a => goal.every((g, i) => a[i] >= g))
        .reduce((a, b) => score(a) <= score(b) ? a : b);
}

var counts = [[5300, 4.2], [6800, 6.0], [5650, 6.6], [2600, 7.0], [4700, 7.0], [3250, 7.3], [3800, 7.5], [3300, 7.8], [9000, 8.2], [5700, 8.5], [7400, 8.5], [6900, 8.7], [4300, 9.0], [5000, 9.5], [6000, 9.5], [7700, 9.5], [2750, 10.0], [5300, 10.0], [6500, 10.0], [8900, 10.5], [6800, 11.0], [3600, 11.4], [4500, 11.5], [9500, 11.5], [5700, 12.0], [5000, 24.0], [6500, 27.0], [7900, 30.0], [5700, 31.0]];

console.log(getApproximation(counts, [2000, 5]));  // [2600, 7]
console.log(getApproximation(counts, [2000, 30])); // [7900, 30]
console.log(getApproximation(counts, [2600, 30])); // [7900, 30]
```

Comment: Thank you really much! This works very good. How can i provide that both numbers of the nearest combination are always bigger than the goal?

Comment: do you have an example?

Comment: How can i achieve that it searches for nearest combination where both values are always the same or bigger than the goal? So when i search for [200,10] and there is [190,8] and [220,12] for example it should choose [220,12] because the goal is above the [190,8].

Comment: if that is always the case, you could filter smaller/unwanted values first.

Comment: In the case of console.log(getApproximation(counts, [2600, 30])); it chooses [2600, 7]. How can i avoid that and achieve the result [7900, 30] instead?

Comment: hello sir, can you elaborate a bit about letter r,v,I, and g. my brain cannot understand. getApproximation function only uses 2 variables, and addAbsDelta function only uses 1 variable

Comment: @astaga, `p` and `s` are callbacks of `reduce` and `r` is the accumulator (return value), `v` is the value from array and `i` is the actual index of the (iterating) array.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the differences of the corresponding array elements, and minimize that similarly to the way you did before.

```js
var userinput1 = $('#userinput1 ').val();
var userinput2 = $('#userinput2 ').val();

counts = [
  ['10', '5'],
  ['20', '10']
];

goal = [userinput1, userinput2];

let closest = counts[0];
let prevDiff = Math.abs(closest[0] - goal[0]) + Math.abs(closest[1] - goal[1]);
counts.forEach(c => {
  let curDiff = Math.abs(c[0] - goal[0]) + Math.abs(c[1] - goal[1]);
  if (curDiff < prevDiff) {
    closest = c;
    prevDiff = curDiff;
  }
});

$('#result1').val(closest[0]);
$('#result2').val(closest[1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Input:
<input id="userinput1 " value="19" type="text">
<input id="userinput2 " value="4" type="text">
Output:
<input id="result1" type="text">
<input id="result2" type="text">
```